# Difference between ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

What are the use cases in which we should use `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `IndexOutOfBoundsException one over another?

Comment: google **"IndexOutOfBoundsException"**

Comment: The difference is that one is used in case of n Array, the other is not.

Answer (score 23):

From docs.oracle.com documentation pages,

> [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) :Thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`
are two classes, which have implemented `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

> [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html): Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

> [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):Thrown by String methods to indicate that an index is either negative or greater than the size of the string. For some methods such as the charAt method, this exception also is thrown when the index is equal to the size of the string.

Answer (score 4):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` is the super class of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (thrown when accessing invalid index in a array) and `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` (thrown when accessing invalid index in a String).

Instances of the base class `IndexOutOfBoundsException` itself are thrown when accessing invalid indices of Lists.

The Javadoc of some methods that throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or its sub-classes contains the base class. For example, `String.charAt` is documented to be throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when it actually throws the sub-class `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if you go out of bounds for an array or String, you will get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. 
For a LinkedList though or some other Collection, you will get the more general IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException indicates the illegal index in its message.

Comment: And `IndexOutOfBoundsException` does not?